# Alternatives for loss functions in python CNTK

Tags: python, deep-learning, cntk

I have created a sequential model in CNTK and pass this model into a loss function like the following:

```
ce = cross_entropy_with_softmax(model, labels)
```

As mentioned [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/wiki/Train-a-multilabel-classifier) and as I have multilabel classifier, I want to use a proper loss function. The problem is I can not find any proper document to find these loss functions in **Python**. Is there any suggestion or sample code for this requirement.

I should notice that I found these alternatives (logistic and weighted logistic) in BrainScript language, but not in **Python**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"my data has more than one label (three label) and each label has more than two values (30 different values)"

Do I understand right, you have 3 network outputs and associated labels, and each one is a 1-in-30 classifier? Then it seems you can just add three `cross_entropy_with_softmax()` values. Is that what you want?

E.g. if the model function returns a triple (ending in something like `return combine([z1, z2, z3])`), then your criterion function that you pass to Trainer could look like this (if you don't use Python 3, the syntax is a little different):

```
from cntk.layers.typing import Tensor, SparseTensor
@Function
def my_criterion(input : Tensor[input_dim], labels1 : SparseTensor[30],
                 labels2 : SparseTensor[30], labels3 : SparseTensor[30]):
    z1, z2, z3 = my_model(input).outputs
    loss = cross_entropy_with_softmax(z1, labels1) + \
           cross_entropy_with_softmax(z2, labels2) + \
           cross_entropy_with_softmax(z3, labels3)
    return loss

learner = ...
trainer = Trainer(None, my_criterion, learner)

# in MB loop:
input_mb, L1_mb, L2_mb, L3_mb = my_next_minibatch()
trainer.train_minibatch(my_criterion.argument_map(input_mb, L1_mb, L2_mb, L3_mb))
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update (based on comments below)**: If you are using a sequential model then you are probably interested in taking a sum over all positions in the sequence of the loss at each position. `cross_entropy_with_softmax` is appropriate for the per-position loss and CNTK will automatically compute the sum of the loss values over all positions in the sequence.

Note that the terminology `multilabel` is non-standard here as it is typically referring to problems with multiple binary labels. The wiki page you link to refers to that case which is different from what you are doing.

**Original answer (valid for the actual multilabel case)**: You will want to use [binary_cross_entropy](https://www.cntk.ai/pythondocs/cntk.ops.html#cntk.ops.binary_cross_entropy) or `weighted_binary_cross_entropy`. (We decided to rename `Logistic` when porting this to Python). At the time of this writing these operations only support {0,1} labels. If your labels are in (0,1) then you will need to define your loss like this

```
import cntk as C
my_bce = label*C.log(model)+(1-label)*C.log(1-model)
```

Comment: I want multilabel classifier, not the binary one!

Comment: We do not distinguish between having a single binary label and many binary labels. The above should work.

Comment: What do you mean many binary labels?! I said multilabel classifier, and it means my data has more than one label (three label) and each label has more than two values (30 different values). Therefore, my questions is `cross_entropy_with_softmax` works well under these situations or not?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I have updated my answer based on this. I think  you will find it more useful for your case now.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, most operators are in the `cntk.ops` package and documented [here](https://cntk.ai/pythondocs/cntk.ops.html). The only exception being the sequence related operators, which reside in `cntk.ops.sequence`.

We have plans to restructure the operator space (without breaking backwards compatibility) to increase discoverability.

For your particular case, `cross_entropy_with_softmax` seems to be a reasonable choice, and you can find its documentation with examples [here](https://cntk.ai/pythondocs/cntk.ops.html#cntk.ops.cross_entropy_with_softmax). Please also check out this [Jupyter Notebook](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/blob/master/Tutorials/CNTK_101_LogisticRegression.ipynb) for a complete example.

Comment: I knew about the `cross_entropy_with_softmax`, as I mentioned. I've also seen the notebook. But, I can't find the solution. Could you copy a sample from your links which works with model and labels like my sample for `cross_entropy_with_softmax`?